# Open Declaration - not working in Eclipse for Zend Framework

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I have tried fixing this the last 3 hours - but just can't seem to get it to work.

On my old laptop - with Zend Eclipse for PHP developers - this was working fine.

Basically in a Controller - if I click on a Model function and say "Open Declaration" - it would open the model class and show me the function - Like I would highlight "loadCourse" right click and say "Open Declaration" and this would take me to the Course.php file to function loadCourse.

$course = Model_Course::loadCourse($course_id);

In my new laptop - I started off with Eclipse Luna - it wasn't working - I tried Eclipse Helios - I know it doesn't have anything to do with the Eclipse versions. I installed all the necessary plugins from 
http://zend-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/eclipse-update/release/

But nothing worked

Finally I came back to installing Zend Eclipse for PHP developers - the version that was running on old laptop.

I setup the project (imported from SVN) - right clicked - Configure - Enable Zend Framework support , PHP support
Nothing seems to work

When I click on Open Declaration - nothing happens.

Not sure What I am missing here
Will appreciate your help
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of search - I came across this eclipse forum where a user suggested to delete the folder

Remove files under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2

Src - http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1065653/?srch=dltk.core.index.sql#msg_1065653

This did the trick for me.

Hope it saves others time

Answer (score 0):

Using

- *Eclipse 2022-06* (`4.24.0`)
- *PHP Development Tools (PDT)*, including *Composer Support* (`7.2.1.202112011741`)

I work on a *Composer*-based project (TYPO3 11 LTS), which has a rather complex project setup with nested *Composer* dependencies [distributed across several subdirectories](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html):

- `vendor/**`
- `public/typo3/sysext/**`
- `public/typo3conf/ext/**`

I import the main project into Eclipse via *Eclipse* -> *File* -> *Import...* -> *PHP* -> *Existing Composer Project*.

Eclipse would only use PHP classes within directory `vendor/**` for content assist features such as autocomplete, "open type hierarchy", or "open declaration".

I fixed this by adding the missing class directories as both *include paths* and *build paths*:

- In the *Project Explorer*, select the main project (in my example called `projectname`).
- Right click on the Eclipse project, or from the menubar select *Project*.
- Select *Properties* -> *PHP* -> *Source Path* -> ***Include** Path* -> *Add Folder...* -> *Select the source folder:*

  - Set a checkmark on the subdirectories which include missing PHP classes. In my case, I set checkmarks on `projectname/public/typo3/sysext` and `projectname/public/typo3conf/ext`).
- Click *OK*.
- A dialog should appear: "*Would you also like to add the selected entrie(s) to the Build Path?*" -> click *Yes*.
- Click *Apply and Close*.

Eclipse will now start to scan for PHP files and update its content assist index. Progress is shown in the lower right corner.

- If this task has finished successfully, content assist should work for all classes on the build path, including classes within the default Composer build path `vendor/**`.
- If it still doesn't work, try the following mitigations:

  - In *Project Explorer*, right click the main project, then select *Composer* -> *Update Build Path*.
  - While the main project is selected, in the menubar select *Project* -> *Clean...* -> click *Clean*. This will take a while to finish (notice progress in the lower right corner).